# Tipo não esperado ao serializar web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialização

Estou tentando usar a Web Api e recebendo este erro ao tentar serializar um array.

> O tipo 'HT.Data.Client' com nome de contrato de dados 'Client:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HT.Data' não é esperado. Considere usar um DataContractResolver se você estiver usando um ou DataContractSerializer adicione quaisquer tipos não conhecidos estaticamente à lista de tipos conhecidos - por exemplo, usando o atributo KnownTypeAttribute ou adicionando-os à lista de tipos conhecidos transmitidos para o serializador.

Minha classe que fica em um projeto diferente da web API:

```
namespace HT.Data
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Tamanho maximo do campo: 128 caracteres. ")]
        public string Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)


        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        public string Secret { get; set; } // Secret


        [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Tamanho maximo do campo: 100 caracteres. ")]
        public string Name { get; set; } // Name


        [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        public int ApplicationType { get; set; } // ApplicationType


        [DataMember(Order = 5, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        public bool Active { get; set; } // Active


        [DataMember(Order = 6, IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatorio")] 
        public int RefreshTokenLifeTime { get; set; } // RefreshTokenLifeTime


        [DataMember(Order = 7, IsRequired = false)]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Tamanho maximo do campo: 100 caracteres. ")]
        public string AllowedOrigin { get; set; } // AllowedOrigin


        public Client()
        {
            InitializePartial();
        }

        partial void InitializePartial();
    }
```

Meu controller:

```
namespace App.ResourceServer.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/sample")]
    public class SampleController : ApiController
    {    
        private UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork();

        [Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<object> Get()
        {    
            Client[] Result = db.ClientRepository.GetAllClients().ToArray(); 
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

E a inicialização da minha API:

```
namespace AngularJSAuthentication.ResourceServer.App_Start
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(Client));

        }
    }
}
```

Como configurar para que a classe seja conhecida/esperada?

Comment: Voce consegue serializar apenas um elemento? Por exemplo em vez deo seu método `Get` retornar `Result` ele retornar `Result[0]` corre tudo certo? A sua classe é parcial (`partial`), mostre a sua classe por completo.

Comment: Não é só tirar o *attribute* `[DataContract]` da classe `Cliente`?

Comment: Tenho a mesma curiosidade do @jbueno. Pq vc adicionou a notação `DataContract`?

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi este erro adicionando no arquivo Global.asax.cs, método Application_Start

```
        //configura retorno json
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como eu resolveria:

1. Crie um projeto de testes;
2. Instancie sua classe com valores dummy;
3. Tente serializar usando o mesmo serializador que sua aplicação principal
   EX: Caso seja NewtonSoft, basta usar JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
4. Provavelmente você terá o mesmo problema, basta inspecionar o erro e identificar qual é a propriedade que ele está reclamando.